# jQuery Selector inside of variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Hi I'm trying to get the IDs of all DIVs, inside another HTML File, with a specific Class.
To load the file I use:

```
$.get("blocks.html", function(data) {
        //here I don't know how :)
});
```

Now what I'm looking for ist something like this:

```
data.$('.block').each(... the rest is no problem
```

so that I use the jQuery selectors not on my page code but instead inside the contend of the data variable.
Thanks for help!

Comment: `$('.block', data)` should do it…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$.get("blocks.html", function(data) {
    var ids = $('<div/>').html(data).find('div.block').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
});
```

Comment: This is a really neat solution, not sure why it doesn't have as many upvotes

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$.get("blocks.html", function(data) {
        $(data).find('.block').each(function(){...});
});
```

If your 'data html' containing element is a '.block', look at @undefined's answer

Comment: @Robj roasted answered first. If anything you copied him :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer really depends on what the responseText looks like that is being returned from the GET request. Based on that you would have to wrap it or not.

### With Parent

If the response is nested inside of a parent tag.

**Response Mark Up:**

```
<div>
   <div id="someId1"></div>
   <div id="yourId" class="block"></div>
   <div id="someId2"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).find('.block');
```

---

### Without Parent

If the response does not have a parent node wrapping the content, you would need to add the parent node or use filter.

**Response Mark Up:**

```
<div id="someId1"></div>
<div id="yourId" class="block"></div>
<div id="someId2"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var htmlFiltered = $(data).filter('.block');
```

or

```
var htmlFiltered = $("<div/>").html(data).find('.block');
```

---

### Getting the ids

You can than use `map()` or `each()` on `htmlFiltered` to get the ids.

**With `each()`**

```
var ids = [];
htmlFiltered.each( function () {
 ids.push(this.id);   
});
console.log(ids);
```

**With `map()`**

```
var ids = $.map(htmlFiltered, function (elem) {
 return elem.id;   
});
console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.get("blocks.html", function(data) {
        $(data).find('.block').each(...
});
```