# How to Replace Element In Variable Using jquery And Get Result In Another Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a variable with HTML content. Similar to "objHtml" variable below.

I want to replace a div tag with Id = 123 with another new div tag.

```
var objHtml = "<div> " +
"<div id='123' class='class1'>Text1</div>" + 
"<div id='124' class='class1'>Text2</div>" +
"</div>";

// I want to construct this new object using "objHtml", and want to replace div having id = 123 with div having id = 125.
// This Html is in the object and not visible or render on the page. 

var newObjHtml = "<div> " +
"<div id='125' class='class1'>Text5</div>" + 
"<div id='124' class='class1'>Text2</div>" +
"</div>";
```

Can any one answer how to replace an element in variable with another element?

Comment: Create a temporary element containing the elements within the string you have, then replace an element you want. After that you can get the HMTL of the temporary element.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590824/jquery-selector-inside-of-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var objHtml = "<div> " +
    "<div id='123' class='class1'>Text1</div>" +
    "<div id='124' class='class1'>Text2</div>" +
    "</div>";

  //Create temporary element
  var elem = $(objHtml);
  
  //Find the element and replace it with new HTML
  elem.find('#123').replaceWith("<div id='125' class='class1'>Text5</div>");

  //Read outerHTML property and update your variable or create new variable
  objHtml = elem.prop("outerHTML");
  
  alert(objHtml)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```